# How do i work with tabs like different xml files?

Tags: android, eclipse, tabs

i have this code

```
package com.example.simgreinirtabs;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TabHost tabHost=(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        tabHost.setup();

        TabSpec spec1=tabHost.newTabSpec("Sími");
        spec1.setContent(R.id.Sími);
        spec1.setIndicator("Sími");

        TabSpec spec2=tabHost.newTabSpec("Sms");
        spec2.setIndicator("Sms");
        spec2.setContent(R.id.Sms);

        TabSpec spec3=tabHost.newTabSpec("Net");
        spec3.setIndicator("Net");
        spec3.setContent(R.id.Net);

        TabSpec spec4=tabHost.newTabSpec("Greina");
        spec4.setIndicator("Greina");
        spec4.setContent(R.id.Greina);

        tabHost.addTab(spec1);
        tabHost.addTab(spec2);
        tabHost.addTab(spec3);
        tabHost.addTab(spec4);
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().height =40;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

with this xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabHost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


    <TabWidget
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
    />

     <FrameLayout
         android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent" >


     <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/Sími"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="340dp"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:paddingTop="60px" >
     </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/Sms"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="60px"
     >

     </LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/Net"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="60px"
     >

     </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/Greina"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="60px"
     >


     </LinearLayout>
     </FrameLayout>

    </TabHost>
```

How can i work with each tab like it is a different xml file. I have 4 tabs, and i want to work with them like i have 4 xml files. Is that possible ? Can i do this another way ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `<include>` tag.

I.e. *layout.xml*:

```
        <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bScan"
        android:layout_below="@+android:id/tabs" >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/login_tab"
            layout="@layout/login" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/user_tab"
            layout="@layout/user" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/rabate_tab"
            layout="@layout/rabate" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/rules_tab"
            layout="@layout/rules" />

    </FrameLayout>
```

Activity:

```
    Context ctx = this.getApplicationContext();

    TabSpec tabLogin = mTabHost.newTabSpec("login");
    tabLogin.setIndicator("login");  
    tabLogin.setContent(R.id.login_tab);

    TabSpec tabUser = mTabHost.newTabSpec("user");
    tabUser.setIndicator("user");  
    tabUser.setContent(R.id.user_tab);

    TabSpec tabRabate = mTabHost.newTabSpec("rabate");
    tabRabate.setIndicator("rabate");  
    tabRabate.setContent(R.id.rabate_tab);
```

Comment: Do i use any of my xml file before putting this in ? and do you put the activity code inside Oncreate R.layout.activity_main ?

Comment: You should put include tags in your framelayout element. Rest could be in onCreate. If you need to access elements inside included element. You need to first View v = findViewById(R.id.user_tab); and then v.findViewById(R.id.element_inside_user_tab);

Comment: i am not getting how you use the activity code u gave me, do i just have to put it below my code, or delet my code and put it then in. Im sry, i am pretty new to android in eclipse. And the name of the layout, does it have to be the samt as the tabs names.